# Is vector::insert allowed to reserve only once and avoid further capacity checks?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, language-lawyer

`vector::insert(dst_iterator, src_begin, src_end)` (insert a range) can be optimized for random-access iterators to reserve the required capacity `src_end - src_begin` first, then perform the copy.

The **main question** I have: Does the Standard also allow `vector::insert` to avoid a capacity check for each copied element? (I.e. not using `push_back` or similar on every element to be inserted)

I'll refer to avoiding this capacity check as "optimization of `insert`".

---

What could go wrong: I can imagine an **iterator with side effects when dereferenced**:

Note: the Standard guarantees the iterators passed to `insert` will be dereferenced exactly once (see end of question).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

template < typename T >
struct evil_iterator : std::iterator < std::random_access_iterator_tag, T >
{
    using base = std::iterator < std::random_access_iterator_tag, T >;

    std::vector<T>* evil_feedback;
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator innocent_iterator;

    evil_iterator( std::vector<T>* c,
                   typename std::vector<T>::iterator i )
        : evil_feedback{c}
        , innocent_iterator{i}
    {}

    void do_evil()
    {
        std::cout << "trying to do evil; ";
        std::cout << "cap: " << evil_feedback->capacity() << ", ";
        std::cout << "size: " << evil_feedback->size() << ", ";

        // better not invalidate the iterators of `*evil_feedback`
        // passed to the `insert` call (see example below)
        if( evil_feedback->capacity() > evil_feedback->size() )
        {
            evil_feedback->push_back( T{} );
            // capacity() might be == size() now
            std::cout << "successful >:]" << std::endl;
        }else
        {
            std::cout << "failed >:[" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    T& operator*()
    {
        do_evil();  // <----------------------------------------
        return *innocent_iterator;
    }


    // non-evil iterator member functions-----------------------

    evil_iterator& operator++()
    {
        ++innocent_iterator;
        return *this;
    }
    evil_iterator& operator++(int)
    {
        evil_iterator temp(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return temp;
    }


    evil_iterator& operator+=(typename base::difference_type p)
    {
        innocent_iterator += p;
        return *this;
    }
    evil_iterator& operator-=(typename base::difference_type p)
    {
        innocent_iterator -= p;
        return *this;
    }

    evil_iterator& operator=(evil_iterator const& other)
    {
        evil_feedback = other.evil_feedback;
        innocent_iterator = other.innocent_iterator;
        return *this;
    }

    evil_iterator operator+(typename base::difference_type p)
    {
        evil_iterator temp(*this);
        temp += p;
        return temp;
    }
    evil_iterator operator-(typename base::difference_type p)
    {
        evil_iterator temp(*this);
        temp -= p;
        return temp;
    }

    typename base::difference_type operator-(evil_iterator const& p)
    {
        return this->innocent_iterator - p.innocent_iterator;
    }

    bool operator!=(evil_iterator const& other) const
    {  return innocent_iterator != other.innocent_iterator;  }
};
```

Example:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> src = {3, 4, 5, 6};
    std::vector<int> dst = {1, 2};

    evil_iterator<int> beg = {&dst, src.begin()};
    evil_iterator<int> end = {&dst, src.end()};

    // explicit call to reserve, see below
    dst.reserve( dst.size() + src.size() );
    // using dst.end()-1, which stays valid during `push_back`,
    //   thanks to Ben Voigt pointing this out
    dst.insert(dst.end()-1, beg, end);  // <--------------- doing evil?

    std::copy(dst.begin(), dst.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, ", "});
}
```

---

#### Questions:

1. Can `vector::insert` be optimized to avoid a capacity check for each inserted element?
2. Is `evil_iterator` still a valid iterator?
3. If so, is `evil_iterator` *evil*, i.e. can it result in UB / non-complying behaviour if `insert` is optimized as described above?

<strike>Maybe my `do_evil` is not evil enough.. have no problems on clang++ 3.2 (using libstdc++):</strike>

Edit 2: Added the call to `reserve`. Now, I'm doing evil :)

> trying to do evil; cap: 6, size: 2, successful >:]
>   trying to do evil; cap: 6, size: 3, successful >:]
>   trying to do evil; cap: 6, size: 4, successful >:]
>   trying to do evil; cap: 6, size: 9, failed >:[
>   1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 135097, 2,

Edit: Why I think the optimization could break this:

1. Consider `dst.size() == dst.capacity() == 2` at the beginning.
2. The call to `insert` requires a new capacity of 6.
3. The optimization enlarges the capacity to exactly 6, then begins to insert the elements by copying from the `src` iterators (`beg`, `end`).
4. This copying is done within a loop where no capacity checks occur. (That is the optimization.)
5. During the process of copying, further elements are added to the vector (w/o invalidating the iterators), in `do_evil`. The capacity now is not sufficient any more to hold the rest of the elements to be copied.

Maybe you had to use `reserve` in the example explicitly to force updating the observable `capacity` before using `do_evil`. Currently, `insert` could reserve some capacity but change what `capacity` returns (i.e. observable capacity) only after the copying is done.

---

What I've found in the Standard so far seems to allow the optimization of `insert`:

[sequence.reqmts]/3

> `a.insert(p,i,j)` [...]
>
> Requires: T shall be EmplaceConstructible into X from *i.
>
> For vector, if the iterator does not meet the forward iterator requirements (24.2.5), T shall also be MoveInsertable into X and MoveAssignable. Each iterator in the range [i,j) shall be dereferenced exactly once.
>
> pre: i and j are not iterators into a. Inserts copies of elements in [i, j) before p

[vector.modifiers] on `insert`

> 1 Remarks: Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity. If no reallocation happens, all the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid. If an exception is thrown other than by the copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator, or move assignment operator of T or by any InputIterator operation there are no effects. If an exception is thrown by the move constructor of a non-CopyInsertable T, the effects are unspecified.
>
> 2 Complexity: The complexity is linear in the number of elements inserted plus the distance to the end of the vector.

Comment: I'm not sure why the comment indicates concern about invalidating `innocent_iterator`, which isn't even referencing the same vector.

Comment: Your "evil" activity is clearly being skipped...

Comment: You're right :) will fix this

Comment: @BenVoigt Added my reasoning and improved the example to... do evil.

Comment: @BenVoigt Maybe I should close/remove the question. I realized it has nothing to do with the optimization. The optimization is fine as long as it doesn't change what `capacity` returns until the copying is done. I still think my example results in UB, but that is due to how libstdc++ has implemented `insert`.

Comment: That output is ugly... but it did insert all the elements you asked, and ended up with the right number of total elements.  But the `2` is in the wrong place and it didn't initialize one of the new elements created by `push_back()`.  I think the implementation is buggy if it moves the end elements and doesn't immediately adjust `size()` before starting to copy.

Answer (score 4):

Looking again, I think this rule (section 17.6.4.9) is a clearer prohibition on what you tried to do:

> Each of the following applies to all arguments to functions defined in the C++ standard library, unless explicitly stated otherwise.
>
> - If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of the function or a pointer invalid for its intended use), the behavior is undefined.

I think this rule applies during the entire duration of the function call, and not only at function entry.

Furthermore, `push_back()` guarantees that (23.3.7.5):

> If no reallocation happens, all the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid.

Your `position` passed to `insert`, which is `dst.end()` as evaluated before the `insert` call, is not *before the insertion point* of the first `evil_feedback->push_back()` call, so it does not remain valid (the fact that you carefully avoided reallocation here does not save you, as you only met half the condition).  Which means the argument you passed to `std::vector::insert`, a function defined in the C++ Standard Library, is invalid during the duration of that call, landing you squarely in the realm of undefined behavior.

---

Previous answer:

I think you violated this precondition that you quoted:

> pre: `i` and `j` are not iterators into `a`.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly: `evil_iterator` having a pointer to the `dst` vector and using `push_back` w/o explicit usage of iterators means that they're "iterators into `dst`"? Or does the Standard intend to say "`i` and `j` shall not modify `dst`"?

Comment: @DyP: I think it means "`i` and `j` shall neither inspect nor modify `dst`".  Having `i` and `j` invalidated because the vector `a` is obviously problematic, but as you point out, so is having `a` mutated by operations on `i` or `j`.

Comment: Why not inspect? Because the vector could temporarily have violated invariants during `insert`?

Comment: @DyP: I quote myself: "Having `i` and `j` invalidated because the vector `a` is obviously problematic".  ok, I left out part of that sentence, it should be "Having `i` and `j` invalidated because the vector `a` **changed** is obviously problematic".  Consider: `a.insert(a.begin(), a.begin()+1, a.begin()+4);`  As soon as space is made to copy the element, and before the copy occurs, `first` and `last` both become invalid.

Comment: Yes, I understood that (that's why I did the check in `evil_iterator::do_evil`). But what has that to do with *inspecting* the vector? Maybe I misunderstand what you mean with *inspect*, I thought of using a `const` member function like `size()`. (Using a non-const member function is obviously problematic as you said.)

Comment: @DyP: Updated, this requirement your `evil_iterator` definitely has intent to violate.

Comment: I think I see you point (in the updated answer), but using `dst.end()` isn't necessary for the example. You could as well use `dts.end()-1` which should stay valid even when `push_back` is called (if `capacity` > `size`).

Comment: @DyP: And if you did, and still avoid reallocation in `evil_iterator`, the code is valid.  I'm not sure why you think this would break if optimized.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: This is more of a comment, I'm using an answer to allow formatting and longer content.  Marking CW because comments should not receive rep)

I believe this is a correct algorithm that avoids O(NM) complexity, if input iterators are random-access:

1. Determine the size of the range to insert (only possible for random-access iterators).
2. Reserve additional space.
3. Adjust size.
4. Move-construct the new tail elements.
5. Move-assign the other intervening elements toward the new end.
6. Copy the source elements into the range left empty by the move.

Comment: "Adjust size": Do you mean what `size()` returns or `resize()` (with default-construction)?

Comment: It's a member function so it can update the internal state returned by size directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my views:

1. Yes; de-referencing can have side effects on your vector (case in point) which could lead to undefined behavior in some cases, but this should not be the case with standard conforming iterators.
2. No; Iterator's are intended as a generalization of pointers - since pointers de-referencing may not have side effects (cannot find reference) the same should be the case for iterators [iterator.requirements.general]. Given this interpretation "optimization of insert" (1) is valid.

Comment: libstdc++ iteratates from first to last and calls `iterator insert( iterator pos, const T& value );` each time - so you will have to be more evil if you are trying to break it.

Comment: `back_insert_iterator` clearly has side-effects, though on `operator=` and not on `operator*`. It would be nice if you could give a reference to the requirement that (certain) operations on iterators should not have side effects.

Comment: I'm not sure if libstdc++ does that, it uses `_M_insert_dispatch` which calls `_M_range_insert` with an appropriate `iterator_tag`. It looks to me like `_M_insert_dispatch` does the optimization.

Comment: @DyP, sorry I was looking @ _M_range_insert in bits/vector.tcc for input iterators, for forward iterators your right - it does seem to do optimization.

Comment: The reason I'm saying de-refference operations may not have side effects is because of [iterator.requirements.general]/3 which states: "Since iterators are an abstraction of pointers, their semantics is a generalization of most of the semantics
of pointers in C++".

This may be interpreted in several ways - but since the operational semantics in [iterator.iterators]/2 is not specified my interpretation is that the semantics for de-reference should be the same as for pointers.