# Is it legal to modify a std::deque during a call to emplace_back?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, deque, libc++

I am using `emplace_back` to add items to an `std::deque`. During its construction, the new item may add other items to the `std::deque` it is being constructed into. This leads to very interesting behavior. Consider this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <string>

struct foo
{
    std::string m_marker;

    foo(std::deque<foo>& into, const std::string& marker, bool createInner = true)
    : m_marker(marker)
    {
        if (createInner)
        {
            std::cout << "Marker is " << m_marker << std::endl;
            into.emplace_back(into, "my other marker", false);
            std::cout << "Marker is now " << m_marker << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::deque<foo> foos;
    foos.emplace_back(foos, "my initial marker");

    std::cout << "There are " << foos.size() << " items in the deque:" << std::endl;
    for (foo& f : foos)
    {
        std::cout << f.m_marker << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It creates a `deque` of `foo` objects. The first object's marker is `"my initial marker"`, and since `createInner` is `true`, it's going to create a second one. I would expect the following result:

```
Marker is my initial marker
Marker is now my initial marker
There are 2 items in the deque:
my initial marker
my other marker
```

However, with clang++ (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) and libc++ (not sure what version it is), this is what I get:

```
Marker is my initial marker
Marker is now my other marker
There are 2 items in the deque:
my other marker
```

As you can see, the `m_marker` field of the first object was overwritten by the second one, and the second one to show up in the deque is now empty. So obviously there's a bug somewhere, and it has to be either that it is undefined behavior to modify a `deque` during a call to `emplace_back`, or that libc++ is not doing its job. Which one is it?

Comment: _why_ would you do that?!

Comment: A related question that you might be interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616253/is-vectorinsert-allowed-to-reserve-only-once-and-avoid-further-capacity-checks

Comment: I would say it's undefined behaviour. The standard only gives guarantees for before and after the function runs.

Comment: For reference purposes: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16238

Comment: Thanks @HowardHinnant! I basically duplicated your answer below. If you like Internet points, feel free to post the same thing and I'll accept yours instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Howard Hinnant answered [on the bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16238), the standard doesn't say anything about this case but it needs to say that it will result in undefined behavior:

> In each case, because of exception safety considerations, the
>   container is not "altered" until the construction of a foo is
>   complete.  That way, if the foo constructor throws, the container
>   state is unchanged.  For example vector.size() is not altered until
>   the foo constructor is complete.  Therefore when the second
>   construction starts before the first one is complete, it is still
>   appending to a zero-length vector.
>
> This is not an issue that can be addressed in the implementation of
>   the containers.  The standard needs to say "don't do that."

So don't expect it to work with any implementation.