# How to combine two vectors containing std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector, stl

If I have two vector containing std::unique_ptr<>, is there a way to add vector b to the end of vector a, thereby deleting vector b?

For example:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> a(&someintvector);

std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> b(&someotherintvector);
```

How would I go about moving vector b to the end of vector a?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9778238/893693) helps you but I am not really sure what the role of the `unique_ptr` is in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You move the contents of `b` into `a`:

```
std::move(std::begin(*b), std::end(*b), std::back_inserter(*a));
```

Comment: Does this work if the vector contains a class too? Because I'm getting the following error: no instance of overloaded function "std::begin" matches the argument list argument types are: (std::unique_ptr<std::vector<CompoundComponent, std::allocator<CompoundComponent>>, std::default_delete<std::vector<CompoundComponent, std::allocator<CompoundComponent>>>>)

Answer (score 4):

Another way to move the elements to `a`:

```
a->insert(a->end(), std::make_move_iterator(b->begin()), std::make_move_iterator(b->end()));
```